# $http is breaking my angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I can create a simple variable with text and display it just fine, but if I use

```
$http.get()
```

It breaks my controller and nothing gets displayed on screen.

Here is my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ietm">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="IetmController">
    <!--  TOC Header  -->
    <header>

    </header>

    <!--  Manuals Container  -->
    <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="manual in toc.manuals">
            <h3>{{manual.title}} <em class="pull-right">{{manual.tm}}</em></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my app.js file

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('ietm', []);

    app.controller('IetmController', ['$http', function($http) {
        var toc = this;
        toc.manuals = [];
        $http.get('main-TOC.json').success(function(data) {
            toc.manuals = data;
        });
    }]);
})();
```

And if it matters, here is my JSON

```
[{
        "docid": "TO2JF11031",
        "location": "2j-f110-3-1",
        "file": "2jf11031.sgm",
        "tm": "2J-F110-3-1",
        "title": "General Information",
        "update": "Thu Jul 7 12:39:17 EDT 2016"
    },
    {
        "docid": "TO2JF11032",
        "location": "2j-f110-3-2",
        "file": "2jf11032.sgm",
        "tm": "2J-F110-3-2",
        "title": "Support Equipment",
        "update": ""
    },
    {
        "docid": "TO2JF11033",
        "location": "2j-f110-3-3",
        "file": "2jf11033.sgm",
        "tm": "2J-F110-3-3",
        "title": "Disassembly",
        "update": "Thu Jul 7 12:39:18 EDT 2016"
    }
]
```

Comment: What's the error? I think you cant GET a json file like that.

Comment: Don't use success(). It's deprecated for a long time in 1.5.x, and removed in 1.6.x. Use then(), as for any promise. Read the $http documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first as mention in the comments, remove the `success` and add  `then` to catch the response.

```
$http.get('main-TOC.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        toc.manuals = response.data;
    }, function(response) {

    });
```

thats solve the error. But data is still not displaying in the html. Because in your controller `this` is assign to variable. so you need use `controller as toc` in the html .

`<body ng-controller="IetmController as toc">`

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/REWSEURygMHhQhMfTmeZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$http.get('main-TOC.json')
.then(function success(response) {
    toc.manuals = response.data;
}, function error(response) {
    // your code when http get fails (optional)
});
```

The reason is `.success()` method for `.get()` was deprecated v1.5 and is no longer available since v1.6. For more information, checkout the following question:

[Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6)

Comment: I tried this and I get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///J:/Neil/AngularIETM/main-TOC.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: @xRuhRohx you need to serve your app from a web server, and access it using the http protocol, in order to be able to use $http. Not from the file system.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without a server?

Comment: @xRuhRohx No, there isn't any.